# Android findViewById cannot resolve variable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm pretty new in Android development

I have this Activity class

```
public class ElencoNotificheActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elenco_notifiche);
    }
    private void setRefreshListener()
    {
        ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.elencoNotificheView);
    }
}
```

In my activity class i have the following error:

> Error:(18, 71) error: cannot find symbol variable elencoNotificheView

But in my layout XML I have:

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/elencoNotificheView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            />
```

Comment: do you understand why R.id worked but R.layout didn't ?

Comment: I didn't investigate deeply... but i think R.id contains ID of the views while R.layout the layouts

Answer (score 3):

it should be `R.id.elencoNotificheView` not `R.layout. elencoNotificheView`

So your ListView should be like this:

```
ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.elencoNotificheView);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have `R.id.elencoNotificheView`:

```
private void setRefreshListener()
{
    ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.elencoNotificheView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.elencoNotificheView);
```

instead of

```
ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.elencoNotificheView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need fix it below code ..

```
 private void setRefreshListener()
    {
        ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.elencoNotificheView);
    }
```

Update

```
ListView elencoNotificheView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.elencoNotificheView);
```